# Add New Records to a Table From Records From another table that are not matching. Cloumn to match are are not primary key and are Varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables:

CaneParcel

```
   FID | Acreage | CODE | DATE_PLANT

128-896   28.6     59   2008-08-01
```

AND

CaneParcelUpdates

```
   FID  | Acreage | CODE   | DATE_PLANT
 128-896     28.6      59    01/04/2013 0h:00:00
 129-963     15.8      01    01/09/2011 0h:00:00
PRE-8596     12.3      14    31/10/2015 0h:00:00
```

I want all new records that are not in the first cp table.

I have tried this but doesnt work

```
If Not Exists(select * FROM CaneParcelUpdates cpu LEFT JOIN CaneParcel cp ON cpu.FIELD_ID = cp.FIELD_ID)
Begin
INSERT INTO CaneParcel (FIELD_ID,ACREAGE, BSI_CODE,DATE_PLANT)
SELECT FIELD_ID, ACREAGE,BSI_CODE,CONVERT(Date,DATE_PLANT) FROM CaneParcelUpdates;
End
```

I am not getting any new records.

Comment: How do you define that a record is already in the first table?

Answer (score 0):

Just do this: insert in `CaneParcel` the values of `CaneParcelUpdates` that don't have a match in `CaneParcel`.

I trimmed the date field and grabbed the 10 first characters to get rid of the hh:mm:ss

```
INSERT INTO CaneParcel (FIELD_ID, ACREAGE, BSI_CODE, DATE_PLANT)
    SELECT 
        FIELD_ID, ACREAGE, BSI_CODE,
        CONVERT(Date,substring(DATE_PLANT,4,2) + '/' + left(DATE_PLANT, 2) + '/' + substring(DATE_PLANT,7,4))
    FROM 
        CaneParcelUpdates cpu
    WHERE
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CaneParcel p 
                    WHERE cpu.FIELD_ID = cp.FIELD_ID);
```

Comment: Hmm. @zip still no luck. Getting the same error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: CAN i bet that in my CaneParcelUpdates table DATE_PLANT is Empty value?

Comment: Indeed if you have empty values, its going to cause an error.You should replace them with null